# Is there a way to count the number of results of a freebase MQL query?

Tags: freebase, mql

For example, I want to get the number of freebase concepts which have a page in the english wikipedia.
Or I want to count the concepts which have the type - book/literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use "return":"count" to get the count of results for a query instead of the actual results of the query.  For "hard" queries this may time out, but for simple queries like the number of books or instances of another type, it should work fine.